# CMD not executing when used in conjunction with ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, docker-registry

My `Dockerfile` looks as below:

```
FROM centos:7
ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo
CMD "helloworld"
```

After building the `centos` image, when I run `docker run -it --name=con1 centos`, I don't see `"helloworld" to be printed.`

Why is the `CMD` not executed?

Comment: Can you please provide more details? I am not able to understand your point.

Comment: @phil indeed, that was a misreading on my part

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "exec" form of both ENTRYPOINT and CMD. With the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo"]
CMD ["helloworld"]
```

Running:

```
docker build -t hello .
docker run --rm hello
```

Produces as output:

```
helloworld
```

---

When you write:

```
ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo
```

That gets transformed into:

```
/bin/sh -c "/bin/echo"
```

And when you write:

```
CMD helloworld
```

That becomes:

```
/bin/sh -c "helloworld"
```

And that's why you're not seeing the behavior you expect. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for some documentation on the topic.

---

Just to demonstrate, if we use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo"]
CMD helloworld
```

Then the output will be:

```
/bin/sh -c helloworld
```

Comment: Do you mean that the combined command becomes `/bin/sh -c "/bin/echo" /bin/sh -c "helloworld"`?

Comment: That is what I am saying, yes.